# Laravel Spark route not working in register method

Tags: laravel

I am overwriting this method

```
public function register(RegisterRequest $request)
```

In my custom `RegisterController`, inside this method I'm trying to get the current route, using various ways like `Route::currentRouteName()`, but this is empty.  The `RegisterRequest` does not seem to contain any route info - can anyone suggest how this flow works and how I might be able to get the route path inside this method ?

Answer (score 0):

That's the function signature in the RegistesUser trait...

```
 /**
     * Handle a registration request for the application.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function register(Request $request)
```

I don't know what your RegisterRequest is but if it is a request you can get the URL from it.. or get it from the Request facade or the request() helper function...

**You can get the uri**...

```
$uri = $request->path();
```

**From the documentation:** https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/requests#request-path-and-method

The is method allows you to verify that the incoming request path matches a given pattern. You may use the * character as a wildcard when utilizing this method:

```
if ($request->is('admin/*')) {
    //
}
```

**Retrieving The Request URL**
To retrieve the full URL for the incoming request you may use the url or fullUrl methods. The  url method will return the URL without the query string, while the fullUrl method includes the query string:

```
// Without Query String...
$url = $request->url();

// With Query String...
$url = $request->fullUrl();
```